# How to view my HardOps operations in edit mode?

Tags: modeling

I am having trouble getting started with the HardOps add on. After I have applied some boolean operations and a bevel to my object I would like to go on edit mode and still see the progress I have made. But when I click edit mode it only shows my base primitive which was the default cube. On the HardOps demos, I see that when they click edit mode they can see the progress they have made and there is a blue wireframe along the bevels, cutouts, etc. How do I enable this?

Thank you!

Comment: I'ts been a whle since I used HardOps, but I understand that one of its features is that it tries to keep the modeling non-destructive by default, meaning stacks and stacks of modifiers get created but never applied, so that no changes are irreversible. I know from experience that there is a way to apply these modifiers through the HardOps UI, but I don't remember how. But I do know that applying the modifiers would have to be done before Edit Mode will show you the changes because Edit Mode is always based on the actual geometry. And modified geometry is not actual geometry until applied.

Comment: Agree with R-800. The idea of *Hard Ops* is working non-destructively so all operations won't change the mesh...

Comment: Thank you for your fast response guys! This totally makes sense. I'm still wondering how Gleb Alexandrov's cube shows the modifiers as if they had been applied when he goes on edit mode as seen in the video attached. (Minute 7:50) You can see on the right that the booleans have not been applied. Thank you for your help!!!                                                                                    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTSFcsdMSk4&t=1730s